# Как сохранить аргумент в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь сделать свою текстовую игру но столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Вот часть кода

```
def stats (XH,GTH=9999999999,ATH=""):
    if ATH == "":
        ATH = 0
        ATH = int(ATH)
    ATH += XH
    if GTH == 0:
        GTH = 9999999999
    if XH < GTH:
        GTH = XH
        print(GTH)
        print(ATH)
```

Мне надо чтобы GTH и ATH не меняли свои значения обратно когда это функция вызывается повторно.
Пример:
**XH=2**
На выводе мы получаем
**GTH=2**
**ATH=2**
При повторном вызове у нас:
**XH=3**
На выводе мы получаем:
**GTH=3**
**ATH=3**
А должны:
**GTH=2**
**ATH=5**
Надеюсь понятно объяснил
P.s команда print в этом коде не нужна она служит проверкой.

```
import random

def game (start,winner="",GNA=0,GNH=0,XH=0,next_try=""):
    if start:
        while True:
                if start in ('E','e'):
                    print('Легкий режим')
                    break
                elif start in ('N','n'):
                    print('Нормальный режим')
                    break
                elif start in ('H','h'):
                    print('Тут надо угадать чилсло от 1 до 250')
                    winner = random.randint(1,250)
                    print(winner)
                    GNA += 1
                    GNH += 1
                    while True:
                        x = input('Введите число: ')
                        if x.isdigit():
                            x = int(x)
                            XH += 1
                        else:
                            print('Введите челое число!')
                            continue
                        if x == winner:
                            print('Вы победили!\nЧисло попыток: ' + str(XH))
                            stats(XH)
                            XH = 0
                            next_try = input ('Хотите продолжить? Y/N: ')
                            if next_try in ('Y','y','yes','Yes','YES'):
                                winner = random.randint(1,250)
                                GNA += 1
                                GNH += 1
                                continue
                            else:
                                winner = random.randint(1,250)
                                menu ()
                                break
                        elif x > winner:
                            print('Загаданое число меньше')
                            continue
                        else:
                            print('Загаданое число больше')
                            continue

def stats (XH,GTH=9999999999,ATH=""):
    if ATH == "":
        ATH = 0
        ATH = int(ATH)
    ATH += XH
    if GTH == 0:
        GTH = 9999999999
    if XH < GTH:
        GTH = XH
        print(GTH)
        print(ATH)



def menu ():
    while True:
        start = input('Куда пойдем E/N/H/exit: ')
        if start in ('E','e'):
            game(start)
            break
        elif start in ('N','n'):
            game(start)
            break
        elif start in ('H','h'):
            game(start)
            break
        elif start in ('exit','Exit','EXIT'):
            pass
menu()
```

Comment: yield и генераторы вам не подойдут ?

Comment: Строчка ATH = int(ATH) не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

В начале игры создаете объект `Pers`. При создании объекта передавайте начальные значения, при вызове метода `stats` меняете значения.

Пример:

```
class Pers:
    def __init__(self, GTH=9999999999, ATH=0):
        self.GTH = GTH
        self.ATH = ATH
        
    def stats(self, XH):
        self.ATH += XH
        if self.GTH <= 0:
            self.GTH = 9999999999
            
        if XH < self.GTH:
            self.GTH = XH


pers = Pers()
pers.stats(XH=2)
print(pers.GTH, pers.ATH)  # 2 2

pers.stats(XH=3)
print(pers.GTH, pers.ATH) # 2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `stats.GTH` и `stats.ATH` внутри функции. Это нечто вроде статических переменных в питоне.

Пример:

```
def foo(parameter):
  foo.static_var += parameter
  print(foo.static_var)

foo.static_var = 0

foo(2)
foo(3)
```

Comment: `def stats (XH,GTH=9999999999,ATH=""):`
    `if ATH == "":`
        `ATH = 0`
        `ATH = int(ATH)`
    `ATH += XH`
    `stats.ATH()`
    `if XH < GTH:`
        `GTH = XH`
        `stats.GTH()`
        `print(GTH)`
        `print(ATH)`
Сделал но выскакивает ошибка
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ATH'
Я просто не совсем понимаю какой атрибут он требует
P.s я тока начинаю изучать python

Comment: @BratAsakura добавил пример

Comment: Что то я не могу понять как это в моём коде сделать. Можешь показать на моём? Как я понял это почти тоже самое что и global Только если глобал пишется внутри функции и уже имеет переменную то с помощью это мы делаем это за пределами функции и присваиваем значение этой переменной? Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: @BratAsakura не могу, т.к. не понимаю логики кода: где должен быть параметр, а где внутреннее состояние. По смыслу похоже на `global`, да

Comment: я добавил код полностью.

Answer (score 0):

Чуть чуть запутано)ATH и GTH выглядят как нечто из генетики)Может ван нужно сохранение в глобальную переменную?Делается так:

```
my_glob_long_liv_var=0
def my_func(inpt:int)->None:
   global my_glob_long_liv_var
   my_glob_long_liv_var+=inpt
```

При каждом вызове с аргументом 3,my_glob_long_liv_var будет прирастать на 3.(суммироваться,акамулироваться))

Comment: Да я знаю что можно использовать global и у меня даже это сделано но я щас хочу немного улучшить код чтобы было меньше лишних строк и global как то не очень выглядит
На счет ATH и GTH Это я просто так сократил для себя :D